# GnuPlot - plot piece of graph in other color

Tags: conditional-statements, gnuplot

I want to plot something like this:

```
plot x linetype ((x < 0.5) ? 5 : 1)
```

of course this is simple example but it doesn't work for me. I just want to have piece of graph in different color then other.
I've got this message:

```
undefined variable: x
```

Does anyone have some idea what wrong is?

Thanks for help.

Yarek

Comment: I changed `lt` to be `linetype`.  At first, I didn't understand what you were going for and I misunderstood -- I thought that you were using `lt` as some kind of comparison operator or something ... anyway, I changed it to be more explicit in the hopes that it'll help clarify the question.  (good question by the way +1 from me)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the `'+'` special file:

```
plot '+' u 1:1:(($1>0.5)?5:1) w lines lc variable
```

You can think of the `+` file as a file with only the x values in the first column.  So, we need to define our plot parametrically.  Here the points are simply (x,f(x)) so it's very easy to do in general

```
f(x)= ... #whatever function you want to plot.
plot '+' u 1:(f($1))  #equivalent to `plot f(x)`
```

And, as I'm pretty sure you've figured out by now, we can use as many columns in the using specification as our plot style will let us -- Including variable line-color as I did above.